# Event native keyboardshow not firing in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic3

I have an app in Ionic 3, and I would like to use the event `native.keyboardshow` to hide the keyboard, but the event is never fired. I'm declaring the event inside the life hook onInit like this:

```
ngOninit() {    
  window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', function(){
    document.body.classList.add('keyboard-open');
    alert('just to check if it's working in mobile);
  });
}
```

Any ideas why the event is not working?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/keyboard
```

Usage

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) { }

...

this.keyboard.show();

this.keyboard.close();
```

source :
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/